# How can I save a modified shapefile in ArcGIS Pro as new shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, editing, arcgis-pro

I downloaded a zipped shapefile and modified it in ArcGIS Pro.

How can I save changes as a new shapefile? I see only the option to save as Layer File.

If it is not possible, how I can edit an existing shapefile and have it in the format of shapefile?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start ArcGis and add data to the Data Frame, if needed.
2. Right-click the layer and select Data > Export Features.
3. Click the Browse button.
4. Navigate to the location where you want to store the shapefile.
5. Type a name for the new shapefile
6. Click the Save button.
7. Click OK.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q37CU.jpg

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I cannot to do it in ArcGis? Do I need to download also ArcMap?

Comment: Take a look at the picture I posted that should help.  This can be done with ArcGis.

Comment: Now it works. I was trying a lot of times before, but I was saving in default MyProject.gdb... which didn't work. When I changed the location, then it could save as shapefile. The easiest things are the most annoying... Thank you! :)